# Display image in reactjs when the image name is stored in local storage

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have stored the image name in local storage.
The question is how to display image in reactjs.

Comment: how did you store them ? can you show the corresponding code please ?

Answer (score 2):

```
const url = localStorage.getItem('imageName')

<img className="attached_image" src={url} alt="my upload" />
```

Get your image name from local storage and save its value in a variable which you can use next in img tag.

Hope this helps.